# Jackson: How to obtain the list of objects from JSON Request

Tags: java, json, jersey, request, jackson

Does anyone know how to get list of objects from JSON request using Jackson annotations? The request, that i think is correct, looks like this:

```
    {   
    "movieName": "test",
    "actors": [     
        {       
        "name" : "Adam",
        "birthDate" : "20-10-2015"          
        }      
      ]  
    }
```

**Actor.java**

```
public class Actor {
    //...
    @JsonProperty(value = "name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty(value = "birthDate")
    private String birthDate;
    //...

    //getters and setters
}
```

**Movie.java**

```
public class Movie {
    //...
    private String movieName;
    private List<Actor> actors;
    //...

    //getters and setters
}
```

In my resource, i used inner class MovieResource.ResourceBody , which contains information about the request as POJO. Mapping "movieName" goes as i expected, but when i try to map the "actors" node, the response is "Unable to process JSON" with HTML code 400 (Bad Request). Here's the resource code:

```
    @Path("/movies")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public class MovieResource {

        public static class RequestBody {
            public RequestBody() {
            }

            public RequestBody(String movieName, List<Actor> actors) {
                this.movieName = movieName;
                this.actors = actors;
            }

            @JsonProperty("movieName")
            private String movieName;

            @JsonProperty(value = "actors")
            private List<Actor> actors;

            //getters and setters
        }

    //CRUD operations
    }
```

Where's the mistake? I preffer to use Annotations everywhere I can.

**EDIT**

**It was all good, i was missing a coma after test , thanks to @peeskillet**

Comment: If you are using jersey, you probably should add the tag

Comment: You're missing a comma after `"test"`